# get the position of a clicked button in Linear layout

Tags: android

So I am working on a linear layout where i add and remove Imagebuttons dynamically. So everytime an imagebutton is clicked and an action is taken, the imagebutton gets removed and changed with another imagebutton/s. The thing is i'd like to maintain the position of the clicked buttons so i can add a new imagebutton at the same location.

```
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpiv =  iv.getLayoutParams();
            il.removeView(iv);

            int ilBtn = R.drawable.ta;

            iv3.setImageResource(ilBtn);
            iv5.setImageResource(ilBtn);

            iv3.setClickable(false);
            iv.setClickable(false);
            il.addView(iv5, lpiv);
            il.addView(iv3, lpiv);
            //iv3.setLayoutParams(lpiv);
```

Comment: map the ids, so you can access them at any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`LinearLayout.indexOfChild(View child)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild%28android.view.View%29) before you call remove, then call [`addView(View child, int index)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) with that index.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me, but wouldnt it be easier just to change the image of the ImageButton instead 
of adding a new button? To distinguish the status just check the image or a status variable.

```
customImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName);
this.status = this.NEW_STATUS;
```

Comment: It's easier but I need different functionality  for each button. So the button can be changed once pressed and two other buttons are added . One of them can be the pressed button. I hope i made it clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Is the code pasted in the question the body of your `OnClickListener`? If so, just modify it to do something like the following before you call `removeView()`:

```
float originalX = view.getX();
float originalY = view.getY();
```

where `view` is the reference to the ImageButton that's being clicked, and then call `setX()` and `setY()` on your new buttons.

Just a heads-up, this will only work if the button being clicked and the ones being added are the same height and with. If they're not, you'll have to do some calculations based on the X/Y of the original one versus the height/width difference to find the same x,y point.

Comment: Also, not quite sure if useful since I don't know the bigger context - Do you actually need to replace the `ImageButton` with a new one, or could you simply get by by changing its drawable? Changing just the image would be a lot less work on the CPU.

Comment: I didn't try yet. It seems to work though. However indexOfChild works pretty well.